# How to insert a image under the text as a pdf background using iText?

Tags: image, insert, background, itext

I need some sample code to insert a image as a pdf background, is there any this kind of sample code ? 
and I have wrote the text well, then i need to insert a image under the text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for water marking the pages in a PDF file.. check the below code. You could also use the Watermarker class.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("text.pdf");
  int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

  // Create a stamper that will copy the document to a new file
  PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, 
    new FileOutputStream("text1.pdf"));
  int i = 1;
  PdfContentByte under;
  PdfContentByte over;

  Image img = Image.getInstance("watermark.jpg");
  BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 
    BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

  img.setAbsolutePosition(200, 400);

  while (i < n) 
  {
    // Watermark under the existing page
    under = stamp.getUnderContent(i);
    under.addImage(img);

    // Text over the existing page
    over = stamp.getOverContent(i);
    over.beginText();
    over.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
    over.showText("page " + i);
    over.endText();

    i++;
  }

  stamp.close();
```

Regards,
Abdel Olakara

Comment: Is it possible to apply layer with itext ? do you have any sample code ? also do you have a MSN ?