# Creating a PDF back page using Itext

Tags: itext

I am currently using iText (Java) to create a PDF document.

This PDf document is meant to be a Businesscard to be printed.

This is part of my code:

```
public void write() throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String extension = ".pdf";
    String file = "testerPDF";

    String filename = file + extension;

    Document doku = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10,20,50,150);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doku, new FileOutputStream(new   File(filename)));

    doku.open();

    Phrase textblock = new Phrase();

    // jetzt durch den Vector iterarieren
    for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        Chunk chunk=new Chunk((String)vector.get(i));

        textblock.add(chunk);
    }

    doku.add(new Paragraph(textblock));

    doku.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

So I need now a way to also write a Back Page for this created PDF. In such a way that the document would look like a Business card on Paper.

Comment: What do you mean by a *back page*? If you just mean another page, just use `doku.newPage()` and add content to this second page.

Comment: If you mean a background image, this response can help you: [How to insert a image under the text as a pdf background][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794604/how-to-insert-a-image-under-the-text-as-a-pdf-background-using-itext