# Tesseract produced searchable PDF with 8bit depth back to 1bit (tess4j)

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j, color-depth

I have a PDFs with 1-bit color depth as an input for OCR processing (tess4j, 5.0.0) with approx. 30kb each. After processing, each PDF has 120-130kb and is saved with 8-bit color depth, which is probably main cause of file size increase.

I would like to know if there is a way to set color depth within Tesseract or associated libs or there is another way to handle this.

```
ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath("/path/to/tessdata");
instance.setPageSegMode(ITessAPI.TessPageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_COLUMN);
List<ITesseract.RenderedFormat> formats = new ArrayList<(Arrays.asList(ITesseract.RenderedFormat.PDF));
instance.createDocumentsWithResults(inputPdf.getPath(), "/path/to/result", formats, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I came up with a workaround - you can specify the output by defining RendererFormat. I changed that from *PDF* to *PDF_TEXTONLY*, which produced a pdf (~7kb) with the text in the right position but without the original scan/image.

```
List<ITesseract.RenderedFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ITesseract.RenderedFormat.PDF_TEXTONLY));
```

Then I used PDFBox functionality to extract image/images from original pdf. It is possible to specify DPI which also helps to reduce the file size.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputPdf);
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
     BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.BINARY);
     ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, "/path/to/pics/picture_" + page + ".png", 300);
}
document.close();
```

Then just add an image to the text-only pdf as a watermark ([How to insert a image under the text as a pdf background using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794604/how-to-insert-a-image-under-the-text-as-a-pdf-background-using-itext)). This helped reduce the size from 120-130 kb to 60 kb with 300 DPI (even less with lower DPI), which is great given that it is an OCR processed pdf with an original size of 30kb. I know this is not the best solution and I'll be happy for any other contribution or answer.

Comment: Tess4J converts PDF to grayscale multipage TIFF image before forwarding it to the Tesseract OCR engine. Alternatively, you could convert the PDF youself with your preferred settings and then send the output image to Tess4J.